# Better multithreading: single functions or collection functions

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing, immutability

I don't know if I worded it correctly, but for a simple example let's say we have a collection of Point3 values (say 1M).

We have a method called Offset that adds another Point3 value on these values, returning new Point3 values. Let's say the method is static.

The Point3 type is immutable.

The question is, should I have a method like this:

```
public static Point3 Offset ( Point3 a, Point3 b )
```

or

```
public static IEnumerable<Point3> Offset ( IEnumerable<Point3> a, IEnumerable<Point3> b )
```

To me #1 seems like a better choice to break the task into separate tasks for different threads.

What do you think? And advantages to #1 or #2?

Comment: Where exactly does the multithreading come into the game?

Comment: For appliy the operation to large number of items in a collection.

Comment: Well I asked because you can only parallelize the second if your enumerator is thread-safe. See also answer from Avish

Comment: #1 can also be parallelized if you apply it to the collection, like a foreach kinda function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1 is the logical core operation. With .NET 4.0 you can achieve the same operation as option 2 using the Zip operator. From memory, instead of:

```
var newPoints = Offset(firstPoints, secondPoints);
```

you'd write:

```
var newPoints = firstPoints.Zip(secondPoints, (p1, p2) => Offset(p1, p2));
```

You may want to consider making `Offset` an extension method on `Point3` if you're using .NET 3.5 as well. (Alternatively, if you control the `Point3` type, this sounds like a logical addition - it would be nice to write `(p1, p2) => p1 + p2` in the call to `Zip`.

If you're not using .NET 4.0 but `Zip` appeals to you, we have an implementation in [MoreLINQ](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) - it's pretty simple.

So far, nothing has been related to multi-threading... now I don't know offhand whether there's a PLINQ implementation of `Zip` in .NET 4.0, but it would make sense for there to be one, IMO.

Comment: Thanks Jon. I agree. I also thought you could do something like this with #1:

var points = Parallel.Foreach(origPoints, Offset) or something. I haven't used TPL so I don't know the full syntax.

If you were to parallelize the offset operation for a collectiion of points using a single offset point3, how would you do it?

Comment: Also you are right, offset is logical addition. I am making high level names for the users of the application where they could use it in the app. With high level it serves more than the + operator, in terms of integration with the app.

Comment: Using a *single* offset is easy - it's just a case of using Select. You can parallelise that easily with PLINQ. (You're just projecting one sequence of points to another in a fixed way.) It's the "offset a sequence by another sequence" which is tricky.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably have the first, and have the second call the first.

Answer (score 2):

#1 seems simpler and cleaner, and you could always parallelize it from outside. I don't see a reason to use #2 exclusively, unless you've neglected to state a crucial detail. If you decide you want to routinely parallelize this sort of loop in the same way, make #2 call #1.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is both. I like having the simpiliest functions possible, so #1 is good. At the same time, convenience methods to operate on lists are darn useful, and can do the hard work of spawning threads if it's appropriate.

One of my beefs with Java (well, almost all languages, but Java is new enough they should have known better) is that they still haven't done a good job making the base library take advantages of multiple threads, or provided many mechanisms to help developers with that. There really should be a generic function to do "apply this function to all elements in this list", and have that function figure out how many cores are available, how big the list is, what the overhead is, and optimize accordingly.